# MDX YTD returning null

Tags: null, ssas, mdx

I'm new to MDX and i was trying to use the YTD function on my cube but I'm getting a problem with it.

If I specify the date in the code it works fine:

```
    WITH MEMBER [Time].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[YTD_SALES] AS
    Aggregate(
        YTD([Time].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[August 2014])
    )
SELECT 
    [Time].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[YTD_SALES] ON COLUMNS,
    [Item].[Item].Children ON ROWS
FROM
    [TBA_SALES]
WHERE
    [Measures].[Sales LCY]
```

but if I replace [March 2014] with CurrentMember the results come back all null.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your Time dimension set as time type?

Another thing what you can try is to see what are you getting as current member.
To try this add:

```
MEMBER YTDStr AS MEMBERTOSTR([Time].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].CurrentMember)
```

then add it to query as you would do for measure:

```
...
SELECT 
    { [Time].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[YTD_SALES], YTDStr } ON COLUMNS,
...
```

EDIT:
You are getting `[Time].[Year - Quarter - Month - Date].[All]` which is top member in hierarchy. Therefore it is not possible to return YTD for all member.

In order to fix this issue you need to add a time dimension member on rows:

```
  WITH MEMBER [Time].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[YTD_SALES] AS
    Aggregate(
        YTD([Time].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[August 2014])
    )
SELECT 
    [Time].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].[YTD_SALES] ON COLUMNS,
    {[Item].[Item].Children, [Time].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].ALLMEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM
    [TBA_SALES]
WHERE
    [Measures].[Sales LCY]
```

I am not sure what you are after in this query, so it's kind of difficult to point you in right direction.

Comment: This query was mostly to test the function.

My problem is that, the '[Time].[Year -  Quarter -  Month -  Date].CurrentMember' code is not returning the current Time member so the quary doesn't work.

Comment: Switch the definition of the YTD_SALES from the Time dimension to the Measures dimension. @Rafal is correct, YTD returns null for the All Member, as it's not a descendant of a specific year and YTD only works for descendants of a Year, of course. However, his change to your query won't work as you have [Time] members on both axis. Change the definition to be [Measures].[YTD_SALES] as YTD( (...), [Measures].[SALES LCY] ), use [Measures].[YTD_SALES] on Columns and remove the WHERE clause.